# How to use CSS with Django forms?

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-forms

I have a `HTML` and `CSS` template done already, and now I have to use `Python` and `Django` to give life to the system. But I stuck into something: how to use my `css` with `django forms` ?

For example, this is what I have use in Django:

```
<label for="id_username">Username:</label>
{{ form.username }}
```

And this is what django generates:

```
<input id="id_username" maxlength="100" name="username" type="text" />
```

As the fields in the form are automatically generated by django, how can I apply style for the `input` field and the others fields too ?
This is my login `form` for example and I would like to use django with the css done so far, but how ?

```
<form class="form-signin" action="" method="post">
  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Pydorado</h2>
    <div class="login-wrap">
      <div class="user-login-info">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" autofocus>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      //..
    </div>
</form>
```

I read the [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/) documentation related to this but I couldn't find any solution so far. Any idea or suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply your styles in the formfield by adding extra attributes like this:

```
myfield = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

I also saw a neat solution where someone created [a custom template tag](http://vanderwijk.info/blog/adding-css-classes-formfields-in-django-templates/) where you could add classes in the template itself.